# Sort JavaScript Object by value (numeric), then key(alphabetically)

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

**priority is to order by highest value, if two or more keys has same value then keys should be sorted alphabetically.**

> Tried below logic, worked for me. Looking for better approach.**

```
//Input Object:
let myObj = {
    hello : 1, // key is Alpha, value is Number
    zello : 5,
    pillow : 6,
    there : 6,
    here : 6,
    peppa : 2,
    boww : 5
};

let flag = true, initialCount=0, finalCount=0, newArr = [];
const keysSorted = Object.keys(myObj).sort((a,b) => myObj[b]-myObj[a]);

for(let i=0; i<keysSorted.length; i++) {
    if(myObj[keysSorted[i]] === myObj[keysSorted[i+1]]) {
        if(flag) {
            initialCount = i;
            flag = false;
        }
    } else {
        if(!flag) {
            finalCount = i;
        }
        if(flag) {
            newArr.push(keysSorted[i]);
        } else {
            let tempArr = keysSorted.slice(initialCount, finalCount+1);
            tempArr.sort();
            newArr.splice(initialCount, 0, ...tempArr);
        }
        flag = true;
        initialCount = 0;
        finalCount = 0;

    }
    
}

console.log(newArr); 
//Output:
//["here", "pillow", "there", "boww", "zello", "peppa", "hello"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below function will simplify your current approach.

```js
function sortObj(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .sort((a, b) =>
            a[1] !== b[1] ?
            b[1] - a[1] :
            b[0] < a[0] ? 1 : -1
        )
        .map(e => e[0]);
}
```

**Working Demo**

```js
function sortObj(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .sort((a, b) =>
            a[1] !== b[1] ?
            b[1] - a[1] :
            b[0] < a[0] ? 1 : -1
        )
        .map(e => e[0]);
}

let myObj = {
    hello : 1, // key is Alpha, value is Number
    zello : 5,
    pillow : 6,
    there : 6,
    here : 6,
    peppa : 2,
    boww : 5
};

console.log(sortObj(myObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather new (es2017) feature, `Object.entries()` that could help out. It returns the object as array and makes it easy to processs.

```js
// returns [["hello",1],["zello",5],["pillow",6],["there",6],["here",6],["peppa",2],["boww",5]]
console.log(Object.entries(myObj));
```

Using `Object.entries()`, we can acces the name and value by index:

```js
function sortByPriorityDescAndNameAsc(i, j) {
  let priority = (i[1] - j[1]) * -1;
  let name = i[0].localeCompare(j[0]);
  // uses sort by name if priority is zero
  return priority || name;
}
// returns ["here", "pillow", "there", "boww", "zello", "peppa", "hello"]
Object.entries(myObj).sort(sortByPriorityDescAndName).map(i => i[0]);
```

We could shorten the code even further but I've kept it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The way to sort by two conditions is to return a negative or positive value if the first sort values aren't the same. If they *are* the same, you do that logic using the *second* value to sort by instead. And if *those* are the same, you return 0.

```js
let myObj = {
    hello : 1, // key is Alpha, value is Number
    zello : 5,
    pillow : 6,
    there : 6,
    here : 6,
    peppa : 2,
    boww : 5
};

const entries = Object
  .entries(myObj)
  .sort(([keyA, valueA], [keyB, valueB]) => {
    return (valueA === valueB)
      ? keyA.localeCompare(keyB); // Return value is compatible with sort functions
      : valueB - valueA;          // If B > A, then result is positive meaning A goes second
  })
  .map(([key, value]) => key);         // Get just the keys

console.log(entries);
```